# How to debug Java server REST application in Eclipse Mars IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have check many debugging tutorials and have checked question related to this here but have some confusion, I want to know the exact method to debug a Java REST application because I haven't debug any Java application yet I have a Java  server (REST) application which I want to debug it in eclipse.

I am using tomcat v7.0 server. I have converted my application to maven recently and need to check response of function at particular break-point.

Comment: Use eclipse tomcat plugin and deploy your RESTs there, start it as debug and test .. if your RESTs are in remote server, you will configure the remote tomcat as debug mode if you can do that, and run a debug from eclipse connecting eclipse to the debug port of the remote tomcat and test ...

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far? You need to simulate the request, run the tomcat in debug mode, add breakpoint in entry point - likely in controller class.

Comment: Run tomcat into debug mode. use breakpoints

Comment: I have followed your step. have run tomcat in c=debug mode, but It is not doing anythis it is started as a normal web app start in browser. no new window opened to instect or check the result.

Comment: I need to check what data the code is having at pertcular step

Comment: How to check output of particular step ?

Comment: set a breakpoint in the code you want to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a debugger option at the top bar, Select that debugger icon. configure it by selection main class where you have main method, The application will start in debugger mode. You must have to select the debugger view (if not selected) to gain full benifit of b=debugger.